# Cannot convert value of type 'Float' to expected argument 'CGFloat'

Tags: ios, swift

I have searched for an answer to this for a while now.
I am an absolute noob when it comes to coding in general, but i figured i'd try my hand at it.
I am trying to write some code to change a color of a view using 3(three) sliders (R,G,B).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorView: UIView!


    @IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func redValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var red = CGFloat(sender.value)
    displayColors()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func greenValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var green = CGFloat(sender.value)
    displayColors()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func blueValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var blue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    displayColors()
    }



    func displayColors(){
        let red = CGFloat(redSlider.value)
        let blue = CGFloat(blueSlider.value)
        let green = CGFloat(greenSlider.value)
        let color = UIColor(
            red: red,
            green: green,
            blue: blue,
            alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redSlider.value, green: greenSlider.value, blue: blueSlider.value, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

However, i get an error on the following line:

```
colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redSlider.value, green: greenSlider.value, blue: blueSlider.value, alpha: 1.0)
```

The error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Float' to expected argument type
>   'CGFloat'

I know that there is a very simple solution, however, since I'm such a noob, i can't come up with the solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CGFloat(redSlider.value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this error since `xxxSlider.value` is of type `Float`, whereas `UIColor` initialiser calls for type `CGFloat` for all four arguments.

You can redeem this error by changing the line into:

```
colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(redSlider.value), green: CGFloat(greenSlider.value), blue: CGFloat(blueSlider.value), alpha: 1.0)
```

However, to achieve the goal of your program, there are more issues that needs to be addressed. I'll go through these below.

---

First of all, you have one `@IBAction` as well as one `@IBOutlet` connected to each slider. With former (action), the latter is really not needed. Hence, remove the `@IBOutlet` connections (code as well as connections)

```
@IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider! // remove (also remove connection)
@IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider! // ...
@IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider! // ...
```

Now, in your `@IBAction`:s, you define a local variable that is never used

```
var red = CGFloat(sender.value) // in @IBAction func redValueChanged(...
var green = CGFloat(sender.value) // ...
var blue = CGFloat(sender.value) // ...
```

In their current form, you don't need these, so remove these also.

Instead, in the scope of the class (see full program below), declare three class variables to hold the current value of each slide (note: these are not to be defined *within* a class method/action/function). Moreover, let these be of type `CGFloat` rather than `Float`, as initialiser of `UIColor` that we use to change background colour takes arguments of type `CGFloat`:

```
var redValue: CGFloat = 0.5 // 0.5: middle slider (init)
var greenValue: CGFloat = 0.5
var blueValue: CGFloat = 0.5
```

In your `@IBAction` closures, change these class variables by the `sender.value` (which holds slider value). After update of variable value, call your `displayColors()` method (that we will look at shortly).

```
// Actions
@IBAction func redValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    redValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    displayColors()
}

@IBAction func greenValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    greenValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    displayColors()
}

@IBAction func blueValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    blueValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    displayColors()
}
```

Your `displayColors()` can be simplified simply to:

```
func displayColors() {
    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Finally, not that the overridden method `viewDidLoad()` is only called once when the ViewController is loaded, so in this case, you can see this as an initialiser for your ViewController. The only thing we want to do here is set the default colour: RGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) = gray.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initial BG color (viewDidLoad() loads only once when ViewController view loads)
    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

And we're done!

---

Wrapping it up, your ViewController class should now look like the following

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Properties
    var redValue: CGFloat = 0.5
    var greenValue: CGFloat = 0.5
    var blueValue: CGFloat = 0.5

    @IBOutlet weak var colorView: UIView!

    // Actions
    @IBAction func redValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        redValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
        displayColors()
    }

    @IBAction func greenValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        greenValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
        displayColors()
    }

    @IBAction func blueValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        blueValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
        displayColors()
    }


    func displayColors() {
        colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initial BG color (viewDidLoad() loads only once when ViewController view loads)
        colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Running your app produces the following behaviour:

[image]

Comment: Im sorry to ask such a dumb question but, where does the "init" go?

Comment: No worries. I'll edit my answer to tell you have to achieve your results rather than what is wrong with your code (as several things are not quite correct, at the moment)

Comment: Thank You so much..... This is the best answer i have gotten within the past couple days....

Comment: @PaulGrapeDrinkVagner You welcome. Good luck on your Swift journey!

Answer (score 8):

`CGFloat` and `Float` are technically different types.  The Swift programming language does not do any numeric type conversion / coercion.  As such, you must explicitly convert from `Float` to `CGFloat` using one of the constructors on `CGFloat`.

```
colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(redSlider.value), green: CGFloat(greenSlider.value), blue: CGFloat(blueSlider.value), alpha: 1.0)
```

You can read more about [Numeric Type Conversion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID324) in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).

Comment: doing so will make my colorView dissapear

Comment: That's a different problem than the one your question is about (type conversion).  Have you checked your values in the debugger?  The green/blue/red parameters that are expected for that `UIColor` initializer are values from 0.0 - 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

In my app using Swift 4, I am using this to convert Float to CGFloat:

```
let slider = sender as? UISlider
let val = CGFloat((slider?.value)!)
```

And then using the variable val as needed, which in my case is for hue, saturation and brightness, e.g.

```
coolButton.saturation = val
```